# How to print this pattern? can anyone explain logic?

Tags: c, logic

[`Star pattern`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st5YD.jpg)

Anyone can make logic for this pattern?
I tried using 2 for loops also.
I just had an interview where I was asked to create star pattern as shown in picture.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char f;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i, j, s, k, l, m;
    for (s = 1; s <= n; s++) //printing
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) //pattern
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    if ((i + j == n + 1)) //star positions
                    {
                        printf("* ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf(" ");
                    }                
                }
                printf("\n");   //next line
            }            
        }        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it will have something to do with `printf("* ");` printing twice as many characters as `printf(" ");`. What happens if you change it to `printf("*");` (without the extra space)? Also, the `printf("\n");` looks like it is in the wrong place (there should be only n^2 lines, not n^3 lines).

Comment: Try `if ((k + j) % n == 1)` `{` `printf("*");` `}` `else` `{` `printf(" ");` `}` and move the `printf("\n");` after the `i` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This problem can solve using 2 for loop.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int num;
        printf("Enter pattern length :");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        
        int matrix=num*num;
        for(int i=0;i<matrix;i++)
        {
    
            for(int j=0;j<matrix;j++)
            {
               if((i+j+1)%num==0)
               {
                   printf("*");
               }
               else
               {
                  printf(" ");
               }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf()` to pad the string for you with the required amount of spaces while printing the asterisk (`*`) character. That way, you don't need to worry about spacing it yourself:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        char pat[n + 1];
        memset(pat, 0, sizeof pat);
        pat[0] = '*';

        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                printf("%*s", n, pat);
            printf("\n");
            pat[j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C Code** for printing this patteren using two for-loop would be

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter pattern length :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int matrix=n*n;
    for(int i=1;i<=matrix;i++)
    {

        for(int j=1;j<=matrix;j++)
        {
           if((i+j-1)%n==0)
           {
               printf("*");
           }
           else
           {
              printf(" ");
           }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go for two loops when you can go for one? If you observe the sequence of characters printed, including newlines, you may see that the last character
printed in every `n*n + 1` sequence is a newline, and the last character in every `n` sequence is a '*'. The rest are spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: star_pattern num\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int dim = n*n;

  for (int i = 0; i < (dim+1)*dim; i++)
  {
    if (i%(dim+1) == dim)
      fputc('\n', stdout);
    else if (i % n == n-1)
      fputc('*', stdout);
    else
      fputc(' ', stdout);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Java<sup>**1**</sup> solution:

```
private static void stars(int n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            var p = " ".repeat(n-j-1) + '*' + " ".repeat(j);
            System.out.println(p.repeat(n));
        }
    }
}
```

or a bit *optimized* (?)

```
private static void stars(int n) {
    var p = (" ".repeat(n-1) + '*').repeat(n+1);
    var l = n*n;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        System.out.println(p.substring(i%n, l+i%n));
    }
}
```

Output for `n = 2`:

> ```
>  * *
> * * 
>  * *
> * *
> ```

and `n = 3`:

> ```
>   *  *  *
>  *  *  * 
> *  *  *  
>   *  *  *
>  *  *  * 
> *  *  *  
>   *  *  *
>  *  *  * 
> *  *  *
> ```

<sup>**1** - question was tagged with Java</sup>